# ValueError: RSA key format is not supported on Python

Tags: python, ubuntu, rsa

Hello When I got this error on my wallet system when ı send another wallet to some coins it cant send and i got this error

My Code:

```
def sendcloudcoin(request):
allify = {}
data = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    senderpubkey = request.POST.get('spubkey')
    senderprivatekey = request.POST.get('sprikey')
    senderwalletid = request.POST.get('swid')
    receiver = request.POST.get('pubkey').strip()
    receiverhex  = hashlib.sha256(base64.b64decode(receiver)).hexdigest()
    amount = request.POST.get('amount').strip()

    if int(amount) <= 0:
        allify['response'] = "not enough amount"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(allify), content_type = "application/json")

    balance = getbalance(senderwalletid)
    if balance is None:
        balance = 0
    if int(amount) > int(balance):
        allify['response'] = "not enough amount"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(allify), content_type = "application/json")
    else:
        first_timestamp = time.time()
        data['senderpublickey'] = str(senderwalletid) #1
        data['receiverhex'] = str(receiverhex)      #2
        data['previous_hash'] = str(transaction.objects.all().last().blockhash) #3
        data['amount'] = str(amount) #4
        data['timestamp'] = str(first_timestamp) #5
        perfect =  miner(first_timestamp, senderwalletid, receiverhex, amount)
        data["nonce"] = str(perfect)
        data = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(data.items()))


        datashash  = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        # print(datashash)
        # print(datashash.encode('utf-8'))

        rsakey = RSA.importKey(senderprivatekey)
        digitalSignature = rsakey.sign(datashash.encode('utf-8'),'')
        digitalSignature = json.dumps(digitalSignature)

        newtrans = transaction(sender=base64.b64encode(senderpubkey.encode('utf-8')),
        senderhexdigest=senderwalletid,
        receiver=receiver,
        receiverhexdigest=receiverhex,
        prevblockhash=transaction.objects.all().last().blockhash,
        blockhash=datashash,
        amount=amount,
        nonce=perfect,
        first_timestamp=first_timestamp,
        P2PKH=digitalSignature,
        verification=True
        )
        newtrans.save()


        allify['response'] = "ok"
        allify['datashash'] = datashash
        allify['datastring'] = json.dumps(allify)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(allify), content_type = "application/json")


        allify['response'] = "ok"
        allify['datastring'] = json.dumps(allify)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(allify), content_type = "application/json")
```

My Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/venv/cloudbank/cloudbank/views.py", line 174, in sendcloudcoin
    rsakey = RSA.importKey(senderprivatekey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 682, in importKey
    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")
ValueError: RSA key format is not supported
```

Comment: Looking at the [PyCrypto code](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/2.6.x/lib/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py#L590), this is raised when it doesn't recognize your key format (whatever `cloudbank/views.py` is passing as `senderprivatekey`). Looks like it's expecting it to start with `-----` (PEM), `ssh-rsa ` (SSH), or the byte `0x30` (DER).

Comment: ı dont understand how can ı do can you help me ?

Comment: Look at the contents of the `senderprivatekey` variable in your above function and make sure it conforms to one of the formats PyCrypto expects. If not, convert it to one. See the link in my previous comment for more information on what PyCrypto expects.